# "Convert" or move my entire Stack Exchange OpenID account to a regular account

Tags: support, openid, stackexchange-2.0

Is it possible to "convert" an OpenID account to a regular Stack Exchange account?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "regular Stack Exchange account". [Stack Exchange recently also became an OpenID provider though](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/stack-exchange-is-an-openid-provider/).

So to convert your account to Stack Exchange OpenID is as simple as

- register on [Stack Exchange OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register)
- change one of your OpenID accounts in your user info (or add the Stack Exchange one if you only have one OpenID account registered ==> you should have 2 registered anyway in case one of your providers doesn't work or gets out of business)

Comment: I will do just that. Thanks for the clarification. =)

Answer (score 3):

To provide further details to fretje's helpful answer, in order to choose your Stack Exchange OpenID in the "add login" page, enter:

```
https://openid.stackexchange.com/
```

in the input box labeled for manually entering your OpenID.